# Castle Windsor resolve named instance and unnamed instance incorrect

Tags: castle-windsor

I have following testing code trying to get one instance for generic and other for special purpose.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Name_And_Named_Instances()
{
//MyClass implemented IMyClass
MyClass genericInstance = new MyClass("generic");
MyClass specialInstance = new MyClass("special");

IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For(IMyClass).Instance(genericInstance));
container.Register(Component.For(IMyClass).Instance(specialInstance).Named("special"));

IMyClass genericOne = container.Resolve<IMyClass>();
IMyClass specialOne = container.Resolve<IMyClass>("special");

Assert.AreSame(genericOne, genericInstance); //true
Assert.AreNotSame(genericOne, specialOne); //false
}
```

I expect to get two different instances, but the result is both genericOne and specialOne points to same objec genericInstance.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't compile:

```
container.Register(Component.For(IMyClass).Instance(genericInstance));
```

Should be:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMyClass>().Instance(genericInstance));
```

Other than that, [the test passes for me](http://mausch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/WindsorInitConfig/WindsorInitConfig/InstanceRegistrationTests.cs) (Windsor 2.5.2)

EDIT:

If you flip the registrations, the test fails. This is by design. When you resolve without an explicit name, you're saying "give me the default component for this service", which in Windsor is the first registered component for that service type, by default.

If you need different components under the same service type, assign explicit names to all of them when registering and resolving.

Comment: My mistake. The posted code had little changed from actual testing code. 
container.Register(Component.For(IMyClass).Instance(genericInstance)); 
should be 
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IMyClass)).Instance(genericInstance)); 

The IMyClass specialOne = container.Resolve<IMyClass>("special"); 
is 
IMyClass specialOne = container.Resolve(typeof(IMyClass),"special"); 
I found last Resolve cause me problem. It should be 
IMyClass specialOne = container.Resolve("special",typeof(IMyClass)); 
The compiler doesn't give me error.

Sorry for bothering all of you.

Comment: I need shot myself. The original test works. Now after I change the register order. Register the named type first then register unnamed type. It give me both same instance again. But if I change order back, then it works. New change:
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IMyClass)).Instance(specialInstance).Named("special"));
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IMyClass)).Instance(genericInstance));